# "Отдых дикарем". Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Точно не знаю, нужны они или нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение слова **дикарь** 'человек, отдыхающий где-либо или путешествующий неорганизованно, без путевки' уже вошло в толковые словари, оно не воспринимается как новое, непривычное, поэтому корректно писать без кавычек: *отдыхать дикарем*. См. http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%E4%E8%EA%E0%F0%E5%EC

Answer (score 2):

Всё, конечно, зависит от контекста.

> Дикарь — 2) перен., разг. нелюдимый,
> необщительный, застенчивый человек; 3)
> жарг. тот, кто едет в курортную
> местность отдыхать без путевки.

Если в контексте имеется в виду одно из этих значений, то кавычки ставить не надо.